# perform field update on rich text field

Tags: process-builder, field-update

I have a rich text field on a custom object which I would like to fill in when another custom picklist field of the same object has some particular value. I know this can't be achieved through workflow field update and in process builder field update on rich text is not available, so any idea on how do I achieve this?

Comment: You can use trigger to update rich text area field.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid trigger!!